# Converting a Cosine Similarity Matrix to JSON in R

Tags: r, json, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity, tibble

I have a Cosine similarity matrix `(csm)`, which looks like this:

```
 csm<-matrix( c(1,0,0.4,0.6, 0,0,1, 0.1,0.4,0.7,0.4,0.1,1,0.9,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.9,1,0.6,0,0.7,0.5,0.6,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)
 rownames(csm) <- c("AAB","AAC","AAD","AAE","AAF")
 colnames(csm) <- c("AAB","AAC","AAD","AAE","AAF")

csm
    AAB   AAC   AAD   AAE    AAF
AAB 1     0     0.4   0.6    0
AAC 0     1     0.1   0.4    0.7
AAD 0.4   0.1   1     0.9    0.5
AAE 0.6   0.4   0.9   1      0.6
AAF 0     0.7   0.5   0.6    1
```

My goal is to build a JSON file that looks like this:

```
    {"AAB":[{"ID":"AAB","value":1},{"ID":"AAC","value":0},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.6},{"ID":"AAF","value":0}],
     "AAC":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAC","value":1},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.1},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.7}],
     "AAD":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAC","value":0.3},{"ID":"AAD","value":1},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.9},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.5}],
     "AAE":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0.6},{"ID":"AAC","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.5},{"ID":"AAE","value":1},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.6}],
     "AAF":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAC","value":0},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.7},{"ID":"AAE","value":0},{"ID":"AAF","value":1}]}
```

What I have done is this:

```
csm %>% as_tibble() %>% 
    gather( ID, value) %>% 
    complete(ID, value)%>%
    jsonlite::toJSON()
```

What I am having is :

```
[{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAB","value":0.1},{"ID":"AAB","value":0.3},{"ID":"AAB","value":0.4},...
```

Could someone help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `stack`

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(lapply(split(df2 <- data.frame(ID = rownames(df), stack(df)), df2$ind), function(x)
    x[, -3]))
#{"AAB":[{"ID":"AAB","values":1},{"ID":"AAC","values":0},{"ID":"AAD","values":0.4},{"ID":"AAE","values":0.6},{"ID":"AAF","values":0}],"AAC":[{"ID":"AAB","values":0},{"ID":"AAC","values":1},{"ID":"AAD","values":0.1},{"ID":"AAE","values":0.4},{"ID":"AAF","values":0.7}],"AAD":[{"ID":"AAB","values":0.4},{"ID":"AAC","values":0.1},{"ID":"AAD","values":1},{"ID":"AAE","values":0.9},{"ID":"AAF","values":0.5}],"AAE":[{"ID":"AAB","values":0.6},{"ID":"AAC","values":0.4},{"ID":"AAD","values":0.9},{"ID":"AAE","values":1},{"ID":"AAF","values":0.6}],"AAF":[{"ID":"AAB","values":0},{"ID":"AAC","values":0.7},{"ID":"AAD","values":0.5},{"ID":"AAE","values":0.6},{"ID":"AAF","values":1}]}
```

Or the `tidyverse` way

```
df %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(ID, value, -row) %>%
    split(.$row) %>%
    map(~.x[, -1]) %>%
    toJSON()
#{"AAB":[{"ID":"AAB","value":1},{"ID":"AAC","value":0},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.6},{"ID":"AAF","value":0}],"AAC":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAC","value":1},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.1},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.7}],"AAD":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAC","value":0.1},{"ID":"AAD","value":1},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.9},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.5}],"AAE":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0.6},{"ID":"AAC","value":0.4},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.9},{"ID":"AAE","value":1},{"ID":"AAF","value":0.6}],"AAF":[{"ID":"AAB","value":0},{"ID":"AAC","value":0.7},{"ID":"AAD","value":0.5},{"ID":"AAE","value":0.6},{"ID":"AAF","value":1}]}
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "    AAB   AAC   AAD   AAE    AAF
AAB 1     0     0.4   0.6    0
AAC 0     1     0.1   0.4    0.7
AAD 0.4   0.1   1     0.9    0.5
AAE 0.6   0.4   0.9   1      0.6
AAF 0     0.7   0.5   0.6    1")
```

Comment: Thanks @Maurits Evers! But I am having this instead when runnning your answer: `{\"AAB\":{\"ID\":[\"AAB\",\"AAC\",\"AAD\",\"AAE\"` ... something wrong?

Comment: @road Ah yes, there was an error in the `tidyverse` approach, sorry. I fixed it. Both base R and `tidyverse` methods should work now.

Comment: hm still having this `"{\"AAB\":{\"ID\":[\"AAB\",\"AAC\",\"AAD\",\"AAE\",\"AAF\"],\"values\":[1,0,0.4,0.6,0]},`

Comment: @road I cannot reproduce. Can you confirm that it works with the sample data you give?

Comment: @Mauritis it is worrking! the was a conflict between two json package on my machine. Thank you!

Comment: @road Odd. What if you write to JSON with `write_json`? Have you tried from a fresh R terminal? I've checked on various machines (Mac, Linux) and different R versions and I cannot reproduce (using `jsonlite_1.5`).

Comment: @road Ah sorry I misread your last comment as "it is not working!". All is well;-)